# geom_contour and geom_label_contour: change decimal places shown on contour lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, contour

I am trying to create a series of contour plots, however, the labels on the contour lines are out to ~10 decimal points. I want the labels to only be 2 decimal points. Below is the original code and resulting plot:

```
    plot <- 
      ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y, z = pred, fill = pred)) +
      geom_tile() + 
      geom_contour(colour = "gray", 
                   size = 0.15) +
      geom_label_contour(aes(z = pred), label.placer = label_placer_flattest()) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(10, "RdYlBu")),
                           limits= c(0, 10)) +
      xlab("Easting") +
      ylab("Northing") +
      coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]
I have tried rounding the breaks in `geom_label_contour(breaks = pretty(round(data, digits = 2)` but the plots still show to 10 decimals in the labels. I've tried similarly rounding the data in `geom_contour(breaks = round(pretty(x = data,n = 10), digits = 2)` Which argument/function is controlling how the contour is calculated and how can I round this value to 2 decimals?

Comment: Please specify the source of `geom_label_contour` and provide a reproducible example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution seemed to be within the breaks argument. Below is the code which worked.

```
breaks <- seq(min(data$pred), max(data$pred), length.out = 10) %>% round(digits = 2)

plot <- 
      ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y, z = pred, fill = pred)) +
      geom_tile() + 
      geom_contour(colour = "gray", 
                   size = 0.15) +
      geom_label_contour(aes(z = pred), label.placer = label_placer_flattest()) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(10, "RdYlBu")),
                           **breaks = breaks,**
                           limits= c(0, 10)) +
      xlab("Easting") +
      ylab("Northing") +
      coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none")
```